# Cannot locate modules in the lib folder Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and DBI despite they exist

Tags: perl

How do I check if   Spreadsheet::WriteExcel is available in my Perl ?

I ran

```
  perldoc -v Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
```

and got the following output which suggests no  Spreadsheet::WriteExcel on  my perl

```
/usr/local/bin/perldoc => Pod::Perldoc v3.13

Formatter class Pod::Perldoc::ToMan successfully loaded!
Will format with the class Pod::Perldoc::ToMan
Searching for Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
Looking for Spreadsheet/WriteExcel in /opt/SYSperl/bin /opt/SYSperl/lib/5.8.6/sun4-solaris /opt/SYSperl/lib/5.8.6 /opt/SYSperl/lib/site_perl/5.8.6/sun4-solaris /opt/SYSperl/lib/site_perl/5.8.6 /opt/SYSperl/lib/site_perl . /opt/pgti/ixp/bin /opt/pgti/ixp/bin /opt/pgti/ixp/bin /opt/CA/uajm/elp/autosys/bin /usr/openwin/bin /usr/bin /usr/ccs/bin /usr/local/bin /opt/RFMadmin/exe /opt/RFMadmin/bin . /apps/risk/bin
No documentation found for "Spreadsheet::WriteExcel".
```

But I saw a code using below line and other functions , working fine on my system

```
$workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($file);`enter code here`
```

Comment: The easiest way to check if something is installed is to run `$ perl -MSpreadsheet::WriteExcel\ 999`. It will either complain that it can't load it, or complain that it cannot load version 999, and tell you which version it has instead. Note the blank space after the backslash.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen modules with `VERSION` numbers as some form of a date, similar to '2016_12_04', which wouldn't complain. I use the method you mentioned above but with a bunch more 9s.

Comment: @SinanÜnür true, that would save one ugly character. :)

Comment: @SinanÜnür `=` is more error prone in that it only works if the module's import() function does version checking if it sees a version (as Exporter does).  The space makes Perl call VERSION in addition to import, which is the most correct thing to do

Comment: @ysth Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have multiple versions of perl present on your system, each of which will look in different places and have different sets of installed modules.

Use the same perl interpreter as your code does and you should be able to verify that it is there with:

```
/path-to-that-perl/perl -le'use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel; print $INC{"Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm"}'
```

There should also be a perldoc installed there that will look in the same places:

```
/path-to-that-perl/perldoc -lm Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
```

It is also possible, though less likely, that the code in question is adding additional directories to `@INC` that says where perl will look for modules, via the -I switch, `use lib`, `PERL*` environment variables, a sitecustomize script, or directly modifying `@INC`.

Comment: I was able to find out the location  for all the modules installed , the path was mentioned in the PATHLIB variable , when I echoed it I got the location, to execute any perl program I think I need to initialize PATHLIB before executing on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Run `perl -e "use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel"` 
if it is installed you do not get an error.

Comment: I get this `Can't locate Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/site_perl /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/vendor_perl .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.`

Comment: Then it is not installed

Comment: I don't think so  as I ran perl -e "use DBI" and i got the same error  Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC isn't the DBI comes by default with the perl ? I went to the lib folder of my perl but dont see DBI there .Being new to perl learning  I am totally confused

Comment: @Vicky No, DBI does not come with the standard perl distribution.

Comment: @melpomene : can you help me locate it ? I know it is installed in my system but I just cannot hapen to locate it ?

Comment: @Vicky Why do you think it is installed on your system?

Comment: @melpomene: because code written by other users using these modules works perfectly

Comment: @Vicky How are you running that other code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152387/discussion-between-vicky-and-melpomene).